Error: headless task failed: exit status 1 : gitpod
getting error while building a gitpod workspace, while I also tried with pip prior to pip3. getting same issue.
.gitpod.dockerfile
FROM gitpod/workspace-full

RUN pyenv install 3.10.7 \
    && pyenv global 3.10.7

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 \
    pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2 \ 
    pip3 install -I elementary-data==0.15.1 \
    pip3 install -I recce==0.24.0 \
    pip3 install -I sqlfluff==3.0.7 \
    pip3 install -I sqlfluff-templater-dbt==3.0.7

...rest of the 

error
Collecting dbt-core==1.8.2
4.050   Downloading dbt_core-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
4.123 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: none)
4.153 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3
------
.gitpod.dockerfile:6
--------------------
   5 |     
   6 | >>> RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
   7 | >>>     pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 \
   8 | >>>     pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2 \ 
   9 | >>>     pip3 install -I elementary-data==0.15.1 \
  10 | >>>     pip3 install -I recce==0.24.0 \
  11 | >>>     pip3 install -I sqlfluff==3.0.7 \
  12 | >>>     pip3 install -I sqlfluff-templater-dbt==3.0.7
  13 |     
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install --upgrade pip &&     pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2     pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2     pip3 install -I elementary-data==0.15.1     pip3 install -I recce==0.24.0     pip3 install -I sqlfluff==3.0.7     pip3 install -I sqlfluff-templater-dbt==3.0.7" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.ReportedErrorEvent","command":"build","error":"exit status 1","file":"build.go:44","func":"func1","level":"error","message":"build failed","serviceContext":{"service":"bob","version":""},"severity":"ERROR","time":"2024-09-30T10:45:50.779922528Z"}
exit

 This task ran as a workspace prebuild
⏱️ Well done on saving 6 minutes

I was trying to setup gitpod with these code snippets, but getting a issue as mentioned above

You're missing some &&s in that command.
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 && \
    pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2 && \
    #(... etc ...)

Otherwise, that command is interpreted as
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2 
# (...etc...)

– hence pip complains it can't find a package called pip3 to install (or, following that, a package called install...). You can replicate that in a regular session with:
$ pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 pip3 install -I dbt-postgres==1.8.2
Collecting dbt-core==1.8.2
  Downloading dbt_core-1.8.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.9 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3

However, it'd be better to just install everything you can in a single pip3 install invocation:
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install -I dbt-core==1.8.2 dbt-postgres==1.8.2 # ... etc ...


Thanks that worked.

@AshutoshSharma Please mark the answer as accepted.

How do you trigger the .gitpod.dockerfile to run those commands? Do they run automatically?
